# Iterate a setState with an index in React JS

Tags: reactjs, use-state

i have a lot of setState that i've declareted with some setState.
I neew to know if there is a mode to iterate the setState passing the index in the name of the state.
The exemple code below:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Component = ()=>{

const array = [
  {
    title: 'Titolo 1',
    description: 'Description 1'
  },
  {
    title: 'Titolo 2',
    description: 'Description 2'
  },
  {
    title: 'Titolo 3',
    description: 'Description 3'
  },
  {
    title: 'Titolo 4',
    description: 'Description 4'
  }
]

  const [state1, setState1] = useState()
  const [state2, setState2] = useState()
  const [state3, setState3] = useState()
  const [state4, setState4] = useState()
  
  
  

  return (
    {array.length > 0 && array.map((el, index)=>(
      <ComponentChild 
        file={state1}
        setFile={setState1}
        />
    ))
  )
}
```

It's possibile to pass the setFile props inside the map loop.
Something like this:

```js
{array.length > 0 && array.map((el, index)=>(
  <ComponentChild 
    file={`state${index}`}
    setFile={`setState${index}`}
    />
))
```

Comment: What is the data for `state1`, `state2`...? That would be clearer for your question and help supporters in answering your question

Comment: It is not important the data of the state. I need only to pass the state and the setState hook as a props using the index lika a costructor of the setState hook

Comment: I think the below answer is fit for your case. We should keep 1 state for all sub-states. If you want to have individual states for each `ComponentChild`, I'd suggest adding them in `ComponentChild` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but you could put all of your states into on useState hook. For example, I'd probably go with this:

```js
const [allStates, setAllStates] = React.useState({
  state1: yourstate1,
  state2: yourstate2,
  ...
})
```

Then you can iterate through your states with index reference or using Object.keys(allStates).

I can't tell exactly what it is that you're attempting, but as a guess I think you might be better capturing everything in a useState:

```js
const [allState, setAllState] = React.useState([
   {
    title: 'Titolo 1',
    description: 'Description 1',
    ...any other state
  },
  {
    title: 'Titolo 2',
    description: 'Description 2',
    ...any other state
  },
])
```

Comment: I tried to follow this way but my problem sussist when I have to cal the setState inside the ChildComponent for a specific index. Example: setState([index]{})

Comment: If you have a state containing an array, you can update with something like `setState(prev => [
...prev.slice(0,index),
<your updated array item>,
         ...prev.slice(index+1)
]).

I might not have that exactly right, but you essentially use the prevState and insert your updated value into the previous state value. There may be a more efficient way to do it with the splice method.